# Python import statement with dot

Tags: python, import

I have an import statement and it has periods.

```
import xyz.app.lib_procs as procs
```

Is it equivalent to`xyz/app/lib_procs`?

Comment: Is what a directory?

Comment: I meant xyz/app/lib_procs.

Comment: This is an EXTREMELY poorly structured question. I'm going to leave you this. Read it and start over. [How to ask a good question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @AustinA 28th question... member for 4 years... you know what? I don't think they care.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I know, but I can always try.

Answer (score 4):

Dots denote namespaces. Usually that means the code is organised into *packages*, and the easiest way to create such packages is by using directories with `__init__.py` files in them.

There are esoteric ways to make such a statement work without directories, using [custom loaders](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) for example, but 99.9% of cases where you come across such a statement you probably have directories yes.

For your example, you would expect there to be a `xyz` directory, containing an `app` directory, in which either lives a `lib_process.py` file that contains the `procs` name, or there is a `lib_process` directory and `procs` is eiter a name available in the `__init__.py` module in that directory, or a `procs.py` module file.

See the [original packages specification](http://legacy.python.org/doc/essays/packages.html).

Answer (score 0):

No, app is a submodule of app, which is itself a submodule of xyz

Comment: But `app` is *almost certainly also a directory*. Inside the `xyz` directory.

Comment: ah, yes. You are correct. Your answer is better. I guess I jumped the gun on this one ><